# Flux parallel-serial execution with groupBy

Tags: java, project-reactor

Say I have this:

```
Flux<GroupedFlux<Integer, Integer>> intsGrouped = Flux.range(0, 12)
   .groupBy(i -> i % 3);
```

and say I have a method:

```
Mono<Integer> getFromService(Integer i);
```

I want to call `getFromService` in parallel for each of the groups, but make sure the calls are serial within each group.

For the above example that would be three parallel streams with these input values:

```
stream 1: 0 -> 3 -> 6 -> 9
stream 2: 1 -> 4 -> 7 -> 10
stream 3: 2 -> 5 -> 8 -> 11
```

I tried this, but it's not doing what I want:

```
Flux.range(0, 12)
   .groupBy(i -> i % 3)
   .flatMap(g -> g.flatMap(i -> getFromService(g.key(), i)))
```

This is calling the service in parallel for all the ints at once. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either [`concatMap`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#concatMap-java.util.function.Function-) or [`flatMapSequential`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMapSequential-java.util.function.Function-) instead of the inner `.flatMap`

If you want sequential *execution* within each group (i.e. only one subscription to `getFromService` at a single time within each group), then use `.concatMap`,  like this:

```java
Flux.range(0, 12)
   .groupBy(i -> i % 3)
   .flatMap(g -> g.concatMap(i -> getFromService(g.key(), i)))
```

If parallel execution within a group is *ok*, but you just care about the order in which the sequence is emitted, then use `flatMapSequential`, like this:

```java
Flux.range(0, 12)
    .groupBy(i -> i % 3)
    .flatMap(g -> g.flatMapSequential(i -> getFromService(g.key(), i)))
```

Another option is to use `.flatMap` with the `concurrency` argument set to `1`, but I'd recommend one of the above instead.

Comment: I am kinda confused on the usage of the inner flatMap, why do we even need that?